# How to map Caps Lock to Esc for Vim in macOS?

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I use vim to develop on my mac and I updated to Mountain Lion yesterday. I was using http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/ this to remap the escape key's function to caps lock to switch between edit and insert modes. I can't really functionally develop in vim without this and it doesn't seem to work in Moutain Lion. I *really* need a solution soon!

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: This as an occasion to develop your flexibility. It's a very useful skill, don't pass this occasion! Anyway, did you follow the install process? If yes, what are the symptoms? Did you send a bug report to the author?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd recommend remapping caps lock to Ctrl and use Ctrl-[. It's easier to hit than Escape and you don't rely on software hacks that might break with the next OS update.

Comment: Just ctrl-c is good, too. I submitted an edit for the title of this question, by the way – it could have been more specific.

Comment: I sent the author an email and he responded asking for patience until the source of mountain lion is released... I didn't even know that apple released their operating system source code. Is that true? Also, I know this is from 2001, but It looked good to me: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip166. I tried it, but xmodmap is not a command my terminal recognizes. I have zsh, and so it asks to autocorrect to _xmodmap, which I tried and it responds with: ___arguments:comparguments:312: can only be called from completion function__

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this:
https://github.com/tekezo/PCKeyboardHack/issues/8#issuecomment-7359829

It worked perfectly for me.

I had grown so accustomed to using caps-lock as esc, that it was killing my productivity until I found this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using the accessibility features of macOS. A usage example:

1. Map Caps Lock to Esc;
2. Map double Shift to Caps Lock.

To achieve (1) go to Settings > Keyboard > Special keys. In the appeared dialog set the desired mappings.

To achieve (2) go to Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard > Hardware > Activate lock keys.

So now if you have taps on you'll even have a logo on your screen notifying you about that.

NB. These are system-wide settings, not only for vim, but I believe it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a special mapping only for one editor, it will only make things more confusing.

NB. The Settings names could differ slightly for you, since I had to translate them from Dutch. Use some fuzzy logic to get to the right place.